# I cannot stop git from looking at my .DS_Store file

Tags: git, gitignore

The first few lines of my .gitignore file looks like this:

```
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.
##
## Get latest from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

.DS_Store
```

So I am confused as I keep seeing this message all the time:

```
'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Test/.DS_Store

Untracked files:
```

It seems like the .gitignore entry is not being recognized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+forget+file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `.DS_Store` file like so:

```
git rm .DS_Store
```

It seems that the file was added once to the repository already, so removing it again might be necessary. From then on, it should be ignored as specified in the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Correct.  .gitignore will not ignore any files that are already tracked.  Also, you can use `git rm --cached` to stage the removal but leave the working tree file, just in case it is something you'd rather keep.